# Mailjet: Adding email to list does not work

Tags: php, email, subscribe, mailjet

I have started to use Mailjet to store the subscription emails using a form. The library I used for this task is "https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-php-simple"

```
include("php-mailjet-v3-simple.class.php");
$apiKey = "xxx";
$secretKey = "yyy";
$mj = new Mailjet($apiKey, $secretKey);
$contact_params = array("method" => "POST", "Email" => "abc@gmail.com");
$contact = $mj->contact($contact_params);

$add_params = array(
    "method" => "POST",
    "ListID" => "11223344",
    "IsActive" => "True"
);
$result = $mj->listrecipient($add_params);
```

But this method does not add the email to the Mailjet list. What did I do wrong here? Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

#### Edit:

See the edits on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30394332/3425488) for a fix if you are using a PHP version older than 5.4.

If possible, try to upgrade instead :-)

---

First of all, thank you for your interest in Mailjet!

Now, before giving you the answer, please know that there is a guide for what you're asking [here](http://dev.mailjet.com/guides/contact-list-guide/) :-) .
Also, the README for the [Github repo for that library](https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-php-simple) has an [example section on contacts and contactslists](https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-php-simple/blob/master/README.md#contact-lists).

Now that you know where to first look the next time you have issues with this library, let's get to the fix, shall we? ;-)

#### The Fix

Your `add_Params` array simply needs a `ContactID` field.
Here is what it should look like:

```
$add_params = [
    "method"    =>  "POST",
    "ListID"    =>  [TheListID],
    "ContactID" =>  [TheContactID],
    "IsActive"  =>  True
];
```

This should solve your issue.

Read on if you want to know why.
Also, full process of creating a contact and adding it to a new list described at the end.

#### The "Why"

The `listrecipient` resource is a way to link a `contact` resource to a `contactslist` resource.
Which means that the API doesn't know what to do when you create a `listrecipient` resource without all the necessary parameters (more info on that [here](http://dev.mailjet.com/email-api/v3/listrecipient/)).

#### The Whole Process

Let's create a `contact` and a `contactslist` resources and add the former to the latter.
(I assume that you have a `$mj` instance of the `Mailjet` class.)

---

## EDIT

Make sure that the contact you're trying to create hasn't already been created.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30394332/3425488) for more infos.

---

```
$makeContactParams = [
    "method"    =>  "POST",
    "Email"     =>  "testSO@example.org"
];

$contact = $mj->contact($makeContactParams);

echo "Contact ID: ".$contact->Data[0]->ID."\n";

$contactslistParams = [
    "method"    =>  "POST",
    "Name"      =>  "TestSO"
];

$list = $mj->contactslist($contactslistParams);

echo "List ID: ".$list->Data[0]->ID."\n\n";    

$listRecepParams = [
    "method"    =>  "POST",
    "ListID"    =>  $list->Data[0]->ID,
    "ContactID" =>  $contact->Data[0]->ID,
    "IsActive"  =>  True
];

$recep = $mj->listrecipient($listRecepParams);
```

I hope this helped you solve your problem and understand why it was there in the first place :-)

Comment: I tried this. But the IDs returned as null values. When I tried to output the result as print_r or var_dump it shows nothing. @Gormador

Comment: You mean that `echo $contact->Data[0]->ID` doesn't show anything?

Comment: nothing shows. I opend a new question for that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30392752/how-to-get-contact-id-in-mailjet-v3-php-wrapper